# Oracle: sort by column with reserved name

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by

How can I sort by column name that is reserved word? For example:

```
select * from some_table t1 order by t1.mode;
```

`mode` is our reserved word. It cannot be changed, moreover I need select to be used with identifier `t1`. So far I've tried:

```
order by t1."mode", "t1.mode", t1.'mode', 't1.mode'
```

Without any luck

Comment: You pasted 10g reserved word list, I'm working with 11g :) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/ap_keywd.htm

Comment: the word is `mode`, not `more`

Comment: never mind, I misread you, sorry ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to use double quotes. But if you use double quotes, column names become case-sensitive. So it's probably

```
ORDER BY t1."MODE"
```

Comment: Funny thing is that I didnt even think about it :) Thank you so much!